# Is the real spherical harmonic (l = 1, m = 0) really 'bigger' than (l = 1, m = 1)?

Tags: plotting, special-functions

Using `SphericalPlot3D` to plot the real spherical harmonic with `l = 1` and `m = 0`:

```
SphericalPlot3D[Abs@Re[SphericalHarmonicY[1,0,Θ,Φ]],Θ,0,π},{Φ,0,2π}]
```

Gives a plot where the height of the lobe is around 0.5 units. Changing to `m = 1` (`SphericalHarmonicY[1,1,Θ,Φ]`) gives a plot rotated onto the xy plane, but now the lobe is around 0.3 units tall.

This seems wrong to me. I'm trying to generate atomic orbitals, and it obviously looks silly to have the *p*-orbitals coming out different sizes..

Comment: `SphericalPlot3D[Abs[SphericalHarmonicY[1, 0, t, f]]^2, {t, 0, \[Pi]}, {f, 0, 2 \[Pi]}]` and `SphericalPlot3D[Abs[1/Sqrt[2] (SphericalHarmonicY[1, 1, t, f] + SphericalHarmonicY[1, -1, t, f])]^2, {t, 0, \[Pi]}, {f, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, PlotRange -> All]`.

Comment: From the documentation: "The spherical harmonics are orthonormal with respect to integration over the surface of the unit sphere." The issue you're running into is that the $m\ne0$ harmonic is complex-valued, with half its energy in the real component and half in the imaginary one. So if you just plot the real component, its amplitude turns out to be only $1/\sqrt2$ of the amplitude of the purely real $m=0$ harmonic. If you want to plot atomic orbitals, you should probably plot both `Sqrt@2 Abs@Re[...]` and `Sqrt@2 Abs@Im[...]` for all the $m>0$ harmonics.

Comment: Just to drive home @march's comment:  The $p_x$ and $p_y$ orbitals in chemistry are linear superpositions of the spherical harmonics.  Under Mathematica's convention, the $p_x$ state is $(Y_{1,1} + Y_{1,-1})/\sqrt{2}$, while the $p_y$ state is $(Y_{1,1} - Y_{1,-1})/\sqrt{2}$.  (Both defined up to phase.)

Answer (score 3):

When you say "*This seems wrong*" to me I interpret this to mean that you expect the same magnitude.

I am completely unfamiliar with `SphericalHarmonicY`. One of the great things about Mathematica is that you can quickly explore.

Here are a mixture of symbolic and numerical computations that lead to the the conclusion that the value with the arguments using `[1,1,...]` should be smaller by `1/Sqrt[2]`.

```
SphericalHarmonicY[1, 0, Θ, Φ]
(* 1/2 Sqrt[3/π] Cos[Θ] *)
```

This is largest when `Θ` is zero.

```
SphericalHarmonicY[1, 0, 0, Φ]
(* Sqrt[3/π]/2 *)
```

Now let's check the second term

```
SphericalHarmonicY[1, 1, Θ, Φ]
(* -(1/2) E^(I Φ) Sqrt[3/(2 π)]Sin[Θ] *)

Re[SphericalHarmonicY[1, 1, Θ, Φ]]
(* -(1/2) Sqrt[3/(2 π)] Re[E^(I Φ) Sin[Θ]] *)
```

This is largest when  `Θ` is `π/2`.

```
Re[SphericalHarmonicY[1, 1, π/2, 0]]
(* -(1/2) Sqrt[3/(2 π)] *)
```

The ratio of the second to the first is given by

```
Re[SphericalHarmonicY[1, 1, π/2, 0]]/SphericalHarmonicY[1, 0, 0, Φ]
(* -(1/Sqrt[2]) *)
```

Which duplicates your result.